# Are there any multithreading static analysis eclipse plugins?

Tags: android, multithreading

Does anyone know of any Eclipse plugins that perform a static analysis in order to detect multithreading bugs?
I am looking for it to work in Java with an Android phone as the target. I am looking for a free plugin.

Comment: Please add details of what is the programming language the multi-threaded app is developed in..as some plugins target specific languages only.

Comment: Also specify the platform on which you want the plugin to run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for open source/free plugins or commercial?

I think, Coverity and Klocwork have introduced commercial plugins as part of extending their main stand alone tools and these should work for multi-threaded applications as well.

May be [this link](http://eclipse-plugins.2y.net/eclipse/plugins.jsp?category=Source+Code+Analyzer) would be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

Klocwork also has a product called Solo that you can download and try to detect multi-threading issues.

http://www.klocwork.com/products/solo/